# Describing multiple choices with two options in a particular order in one statement

Tags: syntactic-analysis, terminology

Say I have three options (or choices if prefer) , A,B and C but one must decide on either A or later having the option of B and C (you cannot choose B or C straight away, only decide that you don't want A, initially) Such that we have:

A or (B or C)

Even though at the end of the day our options are A or B or C. is there a way to represent this in a single concise statement like:
'A or B/C' for example?

Does language like 'or' take two arguments and have orders of operations like the equivalent boolean function for 'or'?

Can we represent multiple options being made as two choices in this way?

We decide between A and (B or C) and then decide between B or C.

Is this possible? Or does language not give us the ability to imply a sort of 'order of operation' essentially treating 'or' similar to an operator, for something like this? Or do we have to rely on expressing it explicitly.

Comment: Is A actually a *Yes/No* choice, then comes the B/C choice?

Comment: it is a selection, you 'choose' option A, or you choose between B/C later think of it like courses at college, one has a single major (A), the other has a choice of two majors (B or C)

Comment: You did not specify how concise the expression has to be that you are looking for. One can easily express the idea in a couple of sentences, as you have yourself done in the question. There is, however, no way of doing it in a natural language, that can at the same time match the clarity and the conciseness that can be accomplished by logical notation.

Comment: Look at the example I have given 'A or B/C' I'm asking really is there a concise way that is similar to treating 'or' like an operator

Comment: @jsw29 would you consider 'A or B/C' as implying that there is a choice before another choice between B and C?

Comment: @user1007028, 'A or B/C' does make it relatively clear that the first choice is between A, on one side, and something that somehow involves B and C, on the other. I don't think, however, that you can assume that the slash will clearly convey the idea that, if one chooses the latter, there will be a second choice between B and C.

Answer (score 1):

"Choose A. Otherwise, choose B or C."

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/otherwise)
> otherwise:
> used after an order or suggestion to show what the result will be if you do not follow that order or suggestion:

Comment: Correct and Concise. I have added the definition of otherwise so as to support the answer.

Comment: This will likely be understood to mean that A is **the** option recommended by the author, that there would be something undesirable about putting oneself in the situation in which one has to choose between B and C (note the words 'order or suggestion' in the quoted definition).

Answer (score 1):

If you reject A, then options B and C become available.